# How Set Authorization headers at HTML Form or at A href

Tags: html, asp.net-web-api, http-headers, token

I have this code:

```
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost:15797/api/values",
                type: 'get',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                headers: {
                    "Authorization": "Bearer " + token
                }
            })
```

works fine, but I want to do that without using Ajax, I want something like that:

```html
        <form action="http://localhost:15797/api/values" method="get">
            <input type="hidden" name="headers[Authorization]" value="Bearer token" />
            <input type="submit" />
        </form>
```

Is it possible? Or just do something like that without XMLHttpRequest? How?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to send the `Authorization` argument in the HTTP request header, it's imposed by OAuth flows. Of course you can change it by making changes in OAuth server's code but if you've got no control on the OAuth server's code it's not possible.

So answering your question, no you can't send them with the form's posted data. However, obviously you can put them in the hidden field and write a JS code to read it from the field and put it in the request header.

e.g.

HTML:

```
<input id="tokenField" type="hidden" />
<input id="submitButton" type="button" />
```

Javascript:

```
$('#submitButton').on('click',function(){
    $.ajax({
          url: "http://localhost:15797/api/values",
          type: 'GET',
          contentType: 'application/json',
          headers: {
                    "Authorization": "Bearer " + $('#tokenField').val()
                 },
          async: false
            }});
```

Notice the `async: false` makes your call synchronous, just like a submit. And if you need to post other data to the server you can change the `type: 'GET'` to `type: 'POST'` and add another field named `data` and pass your form data through its value :

```
<input id="firstName" type="text" />
<input id="lastName" type="text" />
<input id="tokenField" type="hidden" />
<input id="submitButton" type="button" />

$('#submitButton').on('click',function(){
    $.ajax({
          url: "http://localhost:15797/api/values",
          type: 'POST',
          data: { 
                  firstName: $('#firstName').val(),
                  lastName: $('#lastName').val()
                },
          contentType: 'application/json',
          headers: {
                    "Authorization": "Bearer " + $('#tokenField').val()
                 },
          async: false
            })
});
```

Comment: The question is asking "without using Ajax". So I down voted the answer.

Comment: that's right, but as I answered it's not possible without JS code to my knowledge. (unless he can change modify the way that OAuth server works)

Comment: great answer, but not what is asked.