# How (If possible) do you implement Bcrypt and JWT in a website using the following code?

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, bcrypt

I am doing a course in Node.js right now and I am finishing an API with authentication using JWT and Bcrypt.The code can be found on the link below. The code is rather simple and I understand it all but my question is, how would this work for a web app and not using postman? Is it even possible to send these Authentication bearer tokens in req.headers using HTML forms,buttons or some other way from the front end? Is there no way of achieving this without using Passport? Please can somebody give a brief answer to give me an idea on how to do it if possible because I am googling for hours trying to see if this method of authentication can be used for web apps some way.

https://github.com/andrewjmead/node-course-v3-code/tree/master/task-manager/src

Comment: Pls. post your code in the question, not as a link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at your code using the link you provided. The short answer is `YES` you can send the bearer token inside the `req.headers.authorization` from the front end.

The way you send it depends on your front end implementation.

1. If you use fetch API, you can send the bearer token using fetch API request options

```
fetch ('yoururl', {
    method: 'POST',  //your request verb
    body: JSON.stringify('yourObjectData'), //if making a post request
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Authorization": `Bearer ${yourtoken}` //your token can then be accessed using req.headers.authorization 
    },
})
```

See more details how to use fetch api here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

2. If you use jquery, this answer should work also [How Set Authorization headers at HTML Form or at A href](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38422520/how-set-authorization-headers-at-html-form-or-at-a-href)

I'm pretty sure there are other ways of sending the token from the front end. I've used the fetch API.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know fetch can do this. Does it redirect to that page though? Because I know fetch is only used to fetch data from the given page. Or does it not matter? The token is sent so whenever I head to that given route the authentication middleware will work?

Comment: And one more problem. How do I get access to the token to make the fetch call in the first place? I get access to the token on the register and login route but how do I send that token to every route so I have access to it in all my HTML/JavaScript templates?

Comment: I don't fully understand your first question. For the second one, what you can do is to save the token in your local storage using `localStorage.setItem('token', yourTokenString)`.
The token can then be accessed from any page using `localStorage.getItem('token')`. This is the technique I know for now. I'm sure there are other ways.

Comment: I understand that's how you set items in localstorage, but how do I get that token to the client-side so I can set it ? Its only available on my server-side isn't it ? Or do I write that code on the server-side?

Comment: I understand. You simply send it as part of response object when the user signs in. Something like `response.status(200).json({token: generatedtoken})`

Comment: So to summarize this all, I think I got it. I plan on making a form on the GET /users/login route with inputs and a button. I will add an event listener to the button that activates a fetch call to the POST /users/login route with the information from the inputs. It will get the information because of the res.json you just told me about. I then add it to localStorage and redirect to the home page using window.location.replace? Is this all correct?

Comment: Yes. I will suggest you use `window.location.href` though, if you intend to preserve the browser history.

Answer (score 1):

how would this work for a web app and not using postman?

1. First you need to create a HTML form / angular app having login inputs like username and password
2. Then do a ajax call (if its html app) or service call (if angular)  /users/login with posting the user entered values and you will get a token  on succesfful authentication.
3. Then store the token in local storage / cookie and then show the dashboard page.
4. When user navigates to other pages, if its angular app, using interceptor pass the Bearer token on each request. The app will validate and provide the json response.

Is it even possible to send these Authentication bearer tokens in req.headers using HTML forms,buttons or some other way from the front end?

- Yes, you can pass it in req.headers. Ref : https://www.illucit.com/en/angular/angular-5-httpinterceptor-add-bearer-token-to-httpclient-requests/

Is there no way of achieving this without using Passport?

- Yes
- Note: Advantages of using Passport : Passport is Authentication Middleware for Node.JS, it is not for any specific method of authentication, the method for authentication like OAuth, JWT is implemented in Passport by Strategy pattern, so it means that you can swap the authentication mechanism without affecting other parts of your application.Passport makes use of strategies eg Local strategy or with the rise of social networking, single sign-on using an OAuth provider such as facebook or twitter

Ref : full example here https://www.toptal.com/angular/angular-6-jwt-authentication

Comment: Amazing answer that has most of what I need. But one more question, how do I pass the bearer token to other pages if Im not using angular? Only vanilla HTML,JavaScript?

Comment: And is it possible to set an app.local inside a route (for example the users/login ) so it is accessible to all routes? Or is it only possible to set a local in the app.js?

Comment: For vanilla Javascript / HTML you can pass this way  xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + tokenElement.innerHTML);  Ref : https://jonathanmh.com/example-json-web-tokens-vanilla-javascript/ . The second question "app.local" i didn't understand, pls explain with an example

Comment: For example: router.post('/users/login', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const user = await User.findByCredentials(req.body.email, req.body.password)
        const token = await user.generateAuthToken()
        app.local.token = token 
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(400).send()
    }
}) Is it possible to set the token in local storage from this route like this and would it be accessible on every route?

Comment: You should do that in client side (using JS) example : window.localStorage.setItem('access_token', token) and then when you want to retrieve it: window.localStorage.getItem('access_token')

Comment: Bur how do I get access to the token on the client side?