# How to send JWT header when using Stripe checkout

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, stripe-payments

I am trying to have an html page (later a vue.js one) have a stripe checkout form/script/button and then I want to be able to submit that form with an action I set that would then go back to my server (currently local only) and would have an auth token included.

Pretty much what I have is an api gateway that checks if requests are valid via my auth service which is using passport.js JWT strategy. So with each request, I need to send an authorization/bearer token.

My issue is that I am unable to figure out how to send that from a simple HTML page.

The only thing on this test page is the stripe checkout form. I've included the body/form below minus my API key.

I was hoping someone could tell me how to submit the form and have stripe do it's thing while I get the required JWT sent to my Node server.

The best I found was this link but it still doesn't seem to make sense how to do it.
[How Set Authorization headers at HTML Form or at A href](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38422520/how-set-authorization-headers-at-html-form-or-at-a-href)

```
<form action="http://localhost:8090/billing/updateCard" method="POST">
        <script
          src="https://checkout.stripe.com/v2/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
          data-key="<api key>"
          data-amount="cd"
          data-name="Add card"
          data-description="Tagline"
          data-image="../../../favicon.ico"
          data-locale="auto"
          data-currency="usd"
          data-label="Update Card"
          data-panel-label="Update Card"
          data-zip-code="false"
          data-allow-remember-me="false"
          data-email="john.doe@example.com"
          > Update Card
        </script>
      </form>
```

I would like it so that the form is submitted with my auth token. For now, it can be hard-coded into the page and doesn't need to come from the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet here is going to be using the [Custom (Javascript) Checkout integration](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-custom) as that will give you control over what (and how) exactly the data is posted to your Node.js server.

Comment: Not what I am looking for right now, I am not looking to make this production at all. My question pertains how to do it for my dev purposes. I already know how to to custom for when I do prod but I am not spending that time right now, it makes no sense for me to.

Comment: @JoshKirby You could set the Authorization header in your dev middleware. If you are e.g. using webpack with a devServer, you can define multiple config params, e.g. headers. All URLs which are proxied to your backend then have this Authorization header on them.

Comment: You cannot do what you're trying to do without JavaScript, and you cannot use JavaScript with the basic Checkout integration, so if you want to do this, you have to use the custom integration.